# Odd compilation error message

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

The following snippet, in XE6

```
procedure TForm1.Test(CDS : TClientDataSet);
var
  AGuid : TGuid;
  lResult : Longint;
begin
  lResult := SysUtils.CreateGUID(AGuid);
  CDS.InsertRecord([AGuid, '', False]);
end;
```

produces the error message

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(73): E2150 Bad argument type in variable type array constructor
```

Fwiw, in discovering this, I was trying to retrace my steps to a previous version of this routine where the compiler was generating the error

```
E2197 Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter
```

on the line

```
  lResult := SysUtils.CreateGUID(AGuid);
```

despite the fact that what was provoking it turned out to be an error in the subsequent code.

Comment: You've got three answers which none of them addresses the issue you want to be explained, according to  your comments to each one of them. This is a result of failing to ask a question, your post just makes statements.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: Sorry, maybe it would have been clearer if I'd included a question mark at the end of the q's title.  Not meaning to argue, but the three answers managed to address this implicit q with answers of the form "[No, the compiler error message isn't odd because ...]"  and I accepted David's because it was the most succinct.

Comment: The three answers address the implicit question starting with *"for what it is worth"*. And you have mentioned the first error in comments to two of them but the one you accepted. Now you say you've got three satisfactory answers. So be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the declaration of the [`InsertRecord`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.InsertRecord) method:

```
procedure InsertRecord(const Values: array of const);
```

The parameter is a variant open array. [Variant open array parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Variant_Open_Array_Parameters) are implemented internally by being passed as [`TVarRec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TVarRec) instances. And `TVarRec` cannot contain records. Since `TGUID` is a record, it cannot be passed in a variant open array parameter.

Comment: Thanks.  After a good rest, I'll try and recreate the circs which provoked the error I got before this one.  Usually I do my SO stuff in D7 to avoid more recent Delphi quirks, but I was trying to skirt around a D7 prob that the TFields editor will not do a "New Field" on a TGuidField  - it sets the Field Size as '0', whereas it ought to be 38.  Ho hum ...

Answer (score 1):

An array of const cannot take a `TGuid` record type.

An array of const takes items of a TVarRec defined as:

```
TVarRec = record
  case Byte of
    vtInteger:    (VInteger: Integer; VType: Byte);
    vtBoolean:    (VBoolean: Boolean);
    vtChar:       (VChar: Char);
    vtExtended:   (VExtended: PExtended);
    vtString:     (VString: PShortString);
    vtPointer:    (VPointer: Pointer);
    vtPChar:      (VPChar: PChar);
    vtObject:     (VObject: TObject);
    vtClass:      (VClass: TClass);
    vtWideChar:   (VWideChar: WideChar);
    vtPWideChar:  (VPWideChar: PWideChar);
    vtAnsiString: (VAnsiString: Pointer);
    vtCurrency:   (VCurrency: PCurrency);
    vtVariant:    (VVariant: PVariant);
```

Comment: Apparently not, but like I said, I was trying (so far unsuccessfully) to retrace my steps to the other compiler error msg I mentioned.  If/when I manage to do that, I'll update the q.

Answer (score 1):

A type of TGuid is not permitted in array constructors.

TGuid is declared as:

```
  TGUID = packed record
    D1: LongWord;
    D2: Word;
    D3: Word;
    D4: array[0..7] of Byte;
    class operator Equal(const Left, Right: TGUID): Boolean;
    class operator NotEqual(const Left, Right: TGUID): Boolean;
    class function Empty: TGUID; static;
  end;
```

And according to the help, enumerations and records are not supported in array constructors:

> ... because enumerations and records are not supported in array constructors.

Presumably if you wanted the Guid stored, you should convert it to a string using GuidToString:

```
CDS.InsertRecord([GUIDToString(AGuid), '', False]);
```

Comment: The documentation that you link to is sloppy. Array constructors can accept records and enumerated types. Indeed they can accept any types so far as I know. However, array constructors for variable open array parameters cannot accept records.

Comment: "you should convert it to a string using GuidToString"  Indeed, but the problem I was originally having was the compiler gagging on CreateGuid() with the other error msg I mentioned.

Comment: OT: `TGUID.NewGuid.ToString` creates a new GUID and returns it as string (thanks to `TGuidHelper`).